# How to Help Hotel Amend a Booking?

Tags: bookings, hotels, expedia

A hotel that I was going to check in tomorrow sent a strange and apologetic email saying that the hotel was going to be renovated. In it, they requested:

> Could you kindly help us to amend, cancel the booking and change to a
>   different hotel instead?

What exactly does that mean? Expedia allows to Cancel, so that I can do, but how is that me helping the hotel? And what could they mean by *Amend*? Plus, if I Cancel through Expedia, I would not longer get the same rate and, considering how close my arrival date is (tomorrow), there could possibly be severely limited availability.

Comment: Would it mean that they do have a room, just not what you requested? Otherwise, I would take it to mean change your stay to a different time altogether, which, of course, doesn't work for you. Do you have the phone number for the hotel, and could call?

Comment: I would definitely phone them, if they are having renovations and are aware that they have clients coming they could possibly have a list of comparable hotels for you, and could possibly arrange your stay in another hotel.

Comment: It makes me wonder whether the hotel would pay a fee to amend/cancel your booking but you can do it for free. In that you would help them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was no way to contact the hotel as the phone line has been disconnected.

Instead, I called Expedia who were extremely helpful. They  *amended* the bookings (actually had 2 with that hotel) with the small price difference for another similarly-rated hotel nearby. No cancellation fees were due.

One oddity of the system is that the itinerary did not change, it only shows the price for the *other* hotel but still the name and info of the *original*. So it is important to keep the address and contact info of the new hotels.